# Gulp 4 wont complete sass task

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, gulp

There have been a few threads related to this issue but i have not managed to find a solution or explanation for my issue.

**The Problem**

I am using a local version of `Gulp 4.0.0` and my pre-existing `gulpfile.js` was working smoothly.

What i'm doing in my Gulpfile: Watching for changes to Sass files, autoprefixing them and renaming the output file to `theme.scss.liquid` (for Shopify)and finally replacing some curly brackets to escape Liquid variables.

**Sass Task**

```
// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', function (err) {
      sass.logError(err);
      this.emit('end');
    }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(rename('theme.scss.liquid'))
    .pipe(replace('"{{', '{{'))
    .pipe(replace('}}"', '}}'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/'));
});
```

**Watch Task**

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
});
```

**What Happens**

- Running `gulp watch` starts watching for changes.
- Changing or saving my Sass starts the sass task.
- *Nothing else happens*

```
[12:55:33] Starting 'watch'...
[12:55:37] Starting 'sass'...
```

---

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems with `gulp.task` and `gulp v4`

Better take the new gulp 4 syntax.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
// other dependencies
// ....

const sassFn = (cb) => {
  gulp.src('./assets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(rename('theme.scss.liquid'))
    .pipe(replace('"{{', '{{'))
    .pipe(replace('}}"', '}}'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets'));

  cb();
};

const watchFn = () => {
  gulp.watch('./assets/scss/**/*.scss', sassFn);
};

exports.watch = watchFn;
exports.default = watchFn;
```

I removed gulp.series(), because i think it needs at least 2 tasks to run.
Further i changed the `src` and `dest` path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply man, i've (for now) reverted back to gulp 3.9.1 in the package.json and then ran "npm i" so i can get my work done. I'll explore your suggestion over the weekend and then let you know if it works! Thanks again